# Why can't I execute this query even if it seems right to me?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently trying to create a function to register a user in my database but when it tries to do the "insert into" query it returns me an error.

I tried to put the quotes differently each time, I tried to put the values outside the query inside [] : like Values ?, [nom, prenom, ...]
I use post method in postman to try.

```
if(nom && prenom && mail && password && lieu) {
    var rgx=/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)/;
    co.connection.query("SELECT Mail, Password FROM utilisateur WHERE Mail = ? AND Password = ?", [mail, password], function(error, rows){
        if (!!error) {
            console.log('Erreur dans la requête');
        } else if(password.length >= 8 && rgx.test(password)) {
            co.connection.query("INSERT INTO `utilisateur` (`Nom`, `Prenom`, `Mail`, `Password`, `Id_Localisation`) VALUES (`"+nom+"` , `"+prenom+"`, `"+mail+"`, `"+password+"`, `"+lieu+"`)", function(error, rows){
                if (!!error) {
                    console.log("Erreur dans la requête d'envoi");
                } else {
                    res.send('Compte créé avec succès !');
                    res.end();
                }
            })
        } else if(password.length < 8){
            res.send('Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins 8 caractères !');
            res.end();
        } else if(!rgx.test(password)) {
            res.send('Le mot de passe doit contenir au moins une lettre minuscule, une majuscule et un chiffre!');
            res.end();
        } /*else if(rows[0].Mail == mail) {
            res.send('Un compte avec cette adresse existe déjà !');
            res.end();
        }*/
    })

}

else {
    res.send('Veuillez remplir tout les champs !');
    res.end();
}
```

I expect to get "Compte créé avec succès"

Comment: Multiple suggestion:
1. Why not using async await to clean up code, 2. should all the static. sync check done first

Comment: You should either use send or end. Both are same. in some extend.

Comment: "it returns me an error." what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use backticks around the literal values you pass in the `values` clause of the `insert` statement. With single quotes it would work: backtick-delimited names refer to database object names (tables, columns, ...), while single quotes delimit string literals.

But as it is bad practice to inject user-defined strings into an SQL string, you should use arguments, like you did in the first query:

```
co.connection.query("INSERT INTO `utilisateur` (`Nom`, `Prenom`, `Mail`, `Password`, `Id_Localisation`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
    [nom,prenom,mail,password,lieu], function(error, rows){
        // ...etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried to put single quotes and it worked :)

Comment: Good! But please note that it is bad practice to insert strings like that. It is better if you can make it work with parameters.